# Customizing Samba file server

Tags: networking, samba

I customized Samba, but now one computer doesn't see new Ubuntu in network.

In `smb.conf`, I appended this:

```
[develop]
comment = Develop file storage
path = /develop
browsable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
write list = technobulka
create mask = 0755
```

`Workgroup` and `secure` don't change.

Computers in network are:

- notebook Ubuntu 12.04 - it's visible for all
- notebook Windows 7 - visible too
- PC Ubuntu 12.04 with share - don't visible

When I customize this PC last week all works fine, but now I don't know what happens.

**UPDATE**

After installing `system-config-samba` and restarting the PC I can see it in every computer.

`system-config-samba` changed `smb.conf` like this:

```
[develop]
comment = Develop file storage
path = /develop
;browsable = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0755
valid users = technobulka
```

I can connect to the folder but can't create file or folder. What I must change?

Comment: Sorry for my language.

Comment: Can you check if you meant to have a semicolon (;) like this `;browsable = yes`? (That's in the update section of your question)

Comment: This should be reopened. It was only NARQ before the first edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `system-config-samba`. It is graphical and is in the software center. You could also get it by running this terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

**UPDATE**

for providing extra permission you can follow these steps:

[image]